# How can i learn all the required concepts before reading the "Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals "?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

When I first read it I encountred numerous concpets I couldn't understand.

By searching them, I still couldn't understand them because I had no bases.
Where can I learn those concepts ?

Comment: All of them, including the optimization guide, and the parts about virtualization?  Maybe a computer architecture textbook and an operation-system textbook?  For most of it, something like Programming From the Ground Up should cover it.  (And for performance, https://agner.org/optimize/)

Comment: There's both a ton of material behind that title, plus a lot of missing information.  What is included is a description of what each possible instruction actually does, but not necessarily how to use them (e.g. to write an ordinary program, or to write an operating system. The missing information also includes (a) the runtime environment as that is supplied by the operating system rather than by intel, and (b) the programming model, which is to say, how we put instructions together into sequences to get the same things  in assembly / machine code as we can do in the C language or other.

Comment: You are going to have to focus on narrower lines through this material; it probably cannot be digested from start to finish without a lot of additional context.  If you don't know assembly, you might even start with one of several toy processors, like LC-3 or MARIE, MIPS or RISC V even.

Comment: @ErikEidt: Intel's vol.1 actually does have some how-to-use-instructions type of material.  I forget how basic.  Of course nothing about interacting with any specific OS, so not enough to make a complete program, but maybe enough to write a function that processes some data.  Still good point.  And yeah, if you don't know any low-level stuff in other languages (like Unix system calls, or C in general, or OS concepts like memory protection), then yeah RARS or MARS would be a good idea to get your feet wet in a simple "toy" environment.

Comment: I wouldn't inflict MARIE on anyone; one register (accumulator) and the only conditional branch being to jump forward over an unconditional branch make it really annoying to write some things that should be simple for a machine to do.  And especially the branching is the opposite of how one should think about writing branches, as an `if()goto` itself, not to skip some other branch.  It's painful to see that in SO questions about asm for ISAs that don't suck.  At least LC-3 is a binary computer, with bitwise ops; maybe some people don't understand binary before starting asm, hence LMC and MARIE?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it's going to take a while to understand all the concepts. Personally I would start with 16-bit x86 and work your way up from there. I can think of a few good resources off the top of my head:

- Chibiakumas.com
- Low Level Learning on Youtube
- Ben Eater on Youtube

Some of the concepts are typical of most computers in general, so even if you're not learning about x86 directly, it's still useful for understanding since a lot of computer architectures share many similarities (RISC-V and MIPS are very similar, as are 68000 and ARM)

Comment: 16-bit x86 usually requires understanding segmentation at the same time you're trying to learn other basics.  And has a bunch of limitations on what addressing modes are valid.  32-bit user-space is probably the simplest starting point for x86, since modern OSes use a flat memory model.  Once you understand that, then you can look at 16-bit with segmentation, and then bare-metal and booting in 16-bit mode and the switch to protected mode.